# Ajax - illegal invocation error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following function:

```
    function createSkillCard(attributeData,name)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Skillcard/create",
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  {
            request: 'ajax',
            name: name,
            attributes: attributeData
        },
        success: function(data)
        {

        }
    })
}
```

The thing you need to know is that

```
attributeData
```

Is an array of 4 items (strings)

```
name
```

is a string

However whenever i call this i get

```
Illegal invocation
```

error

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you have to pass a stringified version of your object, use `JSON.stringify(yourobject)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard serialisation using `x-www-url-form-encoded` for an array of strings.

Either use some additional serialisation (e.g. JSON) to convert the array into a string and then de